# The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format Stripe

Tags: swift, firebase, stripe-payments

I'm trying to create `StripeEphemeralKeys` within my IOS application using Stripe and Firebase but I keep getting this error when I try and print out the data. `The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.` I can't figure out why!

**Fuctions:**

```
exports.createStripeEphemeralKeys = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
const customerId = data.customerId;
const stripe_version = data.stripe_version;
return stripe.ephemeralKeys
    .create({
        customer: customerId,
        stripe_version: stripe_version
    })
});
```

**Presentation:**

```
func choosePaymentButtonTapped() {

    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

    var paymentContext: STPPaymentContext?

    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("stripe_customers").child(uid)
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in

        guard let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
        guard let customerId = dict["customer_id"] as? String else { return }

        let customerContext = STPCustomerContext(keyProvider: StripeProvider(customerId: customerId))
        paymentContext = STPPaymentContext(customerContext: customerContext)
        paymentContext!.delegate = self
        paymentContext!.hostViewController = self
        paymentContext!.presentPaymentOptionsViewController()
    }
}
```

**Stripe API:**

```
class StripeProvider: NSObject, STPCustomerEphemeralKeyProvider {
lazy var functions = Functions.functions()
let customerId: String

init(customerId: String){
    self.customerId = customerId
}

func createCustomerKey(withAPIVersion apiVersion: String, completion: @escaping STPJSONResponseCompletionBlock) {
    let data: [String: Any] = [
        "customerId": customerId,
        "stripe_version": apiVersion
    ]
    functions
        .httpsCallable("createStripeEphemeralKeys")
        .call(data) { result, error in

            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                completion(nil, error)
            } else if let data = result?.data as? [String: Any] {
                completion(data, nil)
            }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like `onCall` returns a data structure that's different than what you expect: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference

I think you may want to use `onRequest` instead: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#using_express_request_and_response_objects

Comment: I get the error `Failed to load INTERNAL` function?

Comment: The full error is actually `Error Domain=com.firebase.functions Code=13 "INTERNAL" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=INTERNAL}`

Comment: It's some kind of Firebase error then: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors

Comment: Why the downvote?  The response from firebase clearly identifies an INTERNAL error.

Comment: Can you please have a look as this for me and tell me if you know what might be causing the error? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61244065/stripe-create-token-error-the-customer-must-have-an-active-payment-source-attac?noredirect=1#comment108346523_61244065

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. The problem was I was not running the `onCall` function locally. That is, although I had the emulators running locally, I had not told my client to use the emulators. That is done by calling `useFunctionsEmulator(origin: [YOUR HOST])`. More info [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/functions/FirebaseFunctions#useFunctionsEmulator(java.lang.String)).

Comment: This method seems to be deprecated.