# Stripe create token error `The customer must have an active payment source attached`

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm trying to clone the customers stored payment information and use in the connected account by creating a token like this:

```
exports.createToken = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {

var customerId = req.body.customer_id
var accountId = req.body.account_id

console.log(req.id)

stripe.tokens.create(
  { customer: customerId },
  { stripeAccount: accountId }, // id of the connected account
  function(err, token) {
    // callback
    console.log("token:", token)
    console.log("error:", err)
  }
);

})
```

But I keep getting this error `Error: The customer must have an active payment source attached.`  but if I navigate to the customer's section with the stripe dashboard it shows that the customer has 1 card added under the **Cards** section. Do I need to link the customer's account to the connected account? I'm using the IOS SDK to save the card details after following this [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios/basic). I should note that both the `Customer Id` and the `Account Id` are valid and return server side. I don't understand why I can't create a token and then charge the connected accounts card stored in the **Customers** tab.

Comment: what is the customer id you are using?

Comment: @wsw the customer id is cus_H6cCm1laOa it correspondes to the right user

Comment: Is the card attached to the customer is valid and marked as default payment source?

Comment: @AngrejKumar The card is definitely valid as it is the test one that stripe provides (Visa Card), but I'm not sure if the payment source is marked as the default. How can I check this?

Comment: You can [this](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/4648744/1205a3254eb7d22bd11139f5afd7f5fb). Also make sure you have valid expiry date of the card.

Comment: @AngrejKumar You are right, It is not marked as default. How can I make it the default from my server?

Comment: Click on the 3 dots. Check the already attached screenshot.